# DigitalOcean - NodeJS, SocketIO app CORS trying to connect from localhost

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, digital-ocean

I want to access DigitalOcean Node app from my localhost (http://localhost:3000), but I keep getting following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'url.ondigitalocean.app/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OFlEPJW' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
url.ondigitalocean.app/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OFlEPJW:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

**https://admin.socket.io** is working without any issues, but **localhost** is refusing. What am I doing wrong here?

On my Node server I have following code:

```
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const {instrument} = require('@socket.io/admin-ui')
const {jwtDecode, jwtVerify, resignJwt} = require('jwt-js-decode')

const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET

const app = express()

const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: [
      "https://admin.socket.io",
      "http://localhost:3000/",
      "http://localhost:3000",
      "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
      "http://127.0.0.1:3000/",
      "http://localhost:3001",
      "http://localhost:3001/"
    ],
    credentials: true,
  },
});
```

On the client side I have following:

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const token = window.localStorage.getItem('TOKEN') || window.sessionStorage.getItem('TOKEN')

const ioSocket = io('url.ondigitalocean.app', {
    withCredentials: true,
    transportOptions: {
        polling: {
            extraHeaders: {
                'authorization': `${token}`,
            },
        },
    },
});

export const socket = ioSocket
```

Server settings are following:

```
name: dolphin-app
region: fra
services:
- cors:
    allow_headers:
    - '*'
    allow_methods:
    - GET
    - OPTIONS
    - POST
    - PUT
    - PATCH
    - DELETE
    - HEAD
    - CONNECT
    - TRACE
    allow_origins:
    - exact: http://localhost:3000
    - prefix: http://localhost:3000
    - prefix: http://127.0.0.1:3000
    - prefix: http://localhost
  environment_slug: node-js
  github:
    branch: main
    deploy_on_push: true
    repo: 1
  http_port: 8080
  instance_count: 1
  instance_size_slug: basic-xs
  name: websocket
  routes:
  - path: /
  run_command: npm start
  source_dir: /
```

Comment: You are sending `extraHeaders` from client but didn't added or accepting that `extraHeader` in `backend` in socket config

Comment: something like this in `cors` after `origin: [...]` add something like this `allowedHeaders: ["authorization"]` and let me know if it helps!

Comment: Added **allowedHeaders: ["authorization"]** but it didn't help.

Comment: You have to remove "*" from your `cors` and server setting. Because **Credential** is not supported if the CORS header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is `*`

Comment: Removed, but the error is still there.

Comment: add `withCredentials: true` in client side's socket config

Comment: Yea, it is also there, but still nothing.

Comment: As I can see in your client side's code there isn't. can you update your code

Comment: You may try it from different browser because if in some you have using some kind of AdBlocker, AdTracker it may have block it.

Comment: Updated the code. I am testing this in Chrome and FireFox, result is the same.

Comment: I would recommend you setup [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) with options before socket!